# Setting HTML options for <option> tags in select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

In the following ERB:

```
<%= form_for @my_model do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :my_attribute, options_from_collection_for_select(@my_options, :attribute, :name), {class: "select-style"} %>
<% end %>
```

The HTML options at the end will be applied to the generated `<select>` tag in the injected HTML. How can I supply HTML style options that will be applied to the injected `<option>` tags?

The Rails documention [explains how to do this when using `options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select), but not for when using `options_from_collection_for_select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. Where do you get the html options from?
Say, you want a static class for all options:

```
<%= f.select :my_attribute, options_from_collection_for_select(@my_options.map{|o| [o.attribute,{class: 'select-style'},o.name], :first, :last) %>
```

of cause, you can set the class from an attribute of `my_option`.

The trick is, that `options_from_collection_for_select` also extracts html options from each element (the Hash), so you have to construct the elements to include this hash.

But then, you can as well use `options_for_select` (as `options_from_collection_for_select` does internally):

```
<%= f.select :my_attribute, options_for_select(@my_options.map{|o| [o.name,{class: 'select-style'},o.attribute]) %>
```

Comment: Is it `[o.attribute, {class: 'style'}, o.name]` or `[o.attribute, o.name, {class: 'style'}]`? You and @TheShalit disagree on that point.

Comment: The description of `options_for_select` says: `Given a container where the elements respond to first and last (such as a two-element array), the "lasts" serve as option values and the "firsts" as option text`. But: it first removes all the hashes so only two elements are left in each element. That's why @TheShalit's solution is also working.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this option is unavailable.
you can do this:

`<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@my_options.map { |o| [o.attribute, o.name, { class: 'option-style' }] }, :first, :second) %>` - but its ugly.

just do it with options_for_select:

`<%= options_for_select(@my_options.map { |o| [o.attribute, o.name, { class: 'option-style' }] }) %>`

Comment: Is it `[o.attribute, {class: 'style'}, o.name]` or `[o.attribute, o.name, {class: 'style'}]`? You and @MartinM disagree on that point.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can put as much hashes as you want in the array. I like it better when the key and value are first.